# python3 functional programming: Accumulating items from a different list into an initial value

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, python-itertools

I have some code that performs the following operation, however I was wondering if there was a more efficient and understandable way to do this. I am thinking that there might be something in `itertools` or such that might be designed to perform this type of operation.

So I have a list of integers the represents changes in the number of items from one period to the next.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1]
```

Then I need a function to create a second list that accumulates the total number of items from one period to the next. This is like an `accumulate` function, but with elements from another list instead of from the same list.

So I can start off with an initial value `y = 3`.

The first value in the list `y = [3]`. The I would take the second 
element in `x` and add it to the list, so that means `3+1 = 4`. Note that I take the second element because we already know the first element of `y`. So the updated value of `y` is `[3, 4]`. Then the next iteration is `4+2 = 6`. And so forth.

The code that I have looks like this:

```
def func():
    x = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1]
    y = [3]

    for k,v in enumerate(x):
        y.append(y[i] + x[i])
    return y
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have working code that you're looking for peer review to improve, you should ask at [codereview.se] instead; it's the entire reason that site was created. This site is for questions related to non-working (problem) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you *do* what what `itertools.accumulate` does, but you want to add an initial value too. You can do that pretty easily in a couple ways.

The easiest might be to simply write a list comprehension around the `accumulate` call, adding the initial value to each output item:

```
y = [3 + val for val in itertools.accumulate(x)]
```

Another option would be to prefix the `x` list with the initial value, then skip it when `accumulate` includes it as the first value in the output:

```
acc = itertools.accumulate([3] + x)
next(acc) # discard the extra 3 at the start of the output.
y = list(acc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I think that need to be fixed:

1st the condition for the for loop.  I'm not sure where you are getting the k,v from, maybe you got an example using zip (which allows you to iterate through 2 lists at once), but in any case, you want to iterate through lists x and y using their index, one approach is:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
```

2nd, using the first append as an example, since you are adding the 2nd element (index 1) of x to the 1st element (index 0) of y, you want to use a staggered approach with your indices. This will also lead to revising the for loop condition above (I'm trying to go through this step by step) since the first element of x (0) will not be getting used:

```
for i in range(1, len(x)):
```

That change will keep you from getting an index out of range error.  Next for the staggered add:

```
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    y.append(y[i-1] + x[i])
return y
```

So going back to the first append example.  The for loop starts at index 1 where x = 1, and y has no value.  To create a value for y[1] you append the sum of y at index 0 to x at index 1 giving you 4.  The loop continues until you've exhausted the values in x, returning accumulated values in list y.